# How to replace create and edit page of custom object with a new custom component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, custom-object, page-layout

I am new to salesforce and I have requirement where **I need to create a component to create and edit a record for a custom object** (`Appointment__c`), the look & feel and functionality should be same as of the default create and edit form in salesforce but with a added functionality to save/update the record on focus out of a field which is more like a auto save.

[image]

Please let me know how I achieve this. Basically I want to know

1. How can replace the default salesforce edit and create form with my custom form
2. How can I retain the look and feel, also the functionality like validation of required fields and all
3. Should I be creating separate form for Lightning and classic view?

Comment: Have you thought of using Flow?

Comment: You can create a aura component and if you use lightning:recordEditForm. You can replace this aura component in your standard button